# hashcat - is there a way to set minimum password length?

Tags: hashcat

Let's say I have a couple of hashes that I need to bruteforce as dictionary attack didn't work. Is there a way I can tell hashcat to start from a specific password length so it won't waste resources on looking for results that won't work?

Comment: You mean `--pw-min`? If so, you will find this option in the command line help, in the manual, and in various places online.

Comment: `--pw-min` and `--pw-max` were replaced some time ago with `--increment-min` and `--increment-max`. But this information is indeed readily available.

Answer (score 9):

Sounds like you're looking for `--increment-min`. This will start a bruteforce/mask attack at a minimum length.

For example, this will try digits-only candidates, starting with length 7:

```
hashcat -a 3 -m [hashtype] -i --increment-min=7 targethashes.list ?d?d?d?d?d?d?d?d?d?d
```

You didn't directly ask this, but the deeper intent of your question appears to be "what can I do beyond a dictionary attack?"

There are many other options to try before you go full bruteforce - combinator, hybrid, masks. See [hashcat's core attack modes](https://hashcat.net/wiki/#core_attack_modes) for some introductory materials.

Comment: I know that there are more, however none of them work - apparently a random password generator has been used.

Comment: You'd have to do a *lot* of work to rule out many other methods before you can even tentatively start to conclude that. The more methods you try, the more likely you are to be right, though. :)